# set permissions on users mysql with wildcard?

Tags: mysql, permissions

normally one would say:

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'%'

Can we use a wildcard where we can target specific databases only like this:

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SHOP%.* TO 'monty'@'%'

We would like to give insert privileges to a user on databases that start with prefix "SHOP"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can.  See the [GRANT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html).  Here's a quote from that page:

> The “`_`” and “`%`” wildcards are allowed
>   when specifying database names in
>   GRANT statements that grant privileges
>   at the global or database levels. This
>   means, for example, that if you want
>   to use a “`_`” character as part of a
>   database name, you should specify it
>   as “`\_`” in the GRANT statement, to
>   prevent the user from being able to
>   access additional databases matching
>   the wildcard pattern; for example,
>   GRANT ... ON `foo\_bar`.* TO

Comment: thanks but I get an error when doing this: grant select, insert, delete, update on "shop%".* to 'someone'@'localhost'; ->  You have an error in your SQL syntax

Comment: You must use back-ticks around the database name: `grant select, insert, delete, update on \`shop%\`.* to 'someone'@'localhost';`

Comment: Note, on AWS RDS MySQL servers, you need to select the database first with 'use somedbNameDoesntMatter;' then this grant command will work.